# Online user guide plus PDF download

Tags: php, html, xml

At the moment I am managing my user guide using Microsoft Word 2003 and am converting it to a PDF file that can be downloaded from website plus is included by product installer.

I would like to move to a mechanism that achieves the following:

- Generates PDF file with clickable TOC and front page
- Generates HTML5 compliant output per chapter/section but without HTML skeleton
- Generates JSON TOC for user guide (chapter/section outline)

I would like to package the PDF file with the distributed product.

I would like to create some simple PHP scripts that generate HTML pages with a context sensitive TOC (showing sections of current chapter) plus showing the relevant documentation.

I have no issues with developing the PHP scripts to achieve this, but I would like to know how I can generate the above outputs. I would preferably like to type documentation using an off-the-shelf GUI. I am happy to write XSLT2 stylesheets to perform any necessary conversions.

To give people an idea of what I am after:

- Current PDF manual: http://rotorz.com/tilesystem/user-guide.pdf
- API documentation which is generated using custom XSLT2 stylesheets into a bunch of "incomplete" HTML files, with a JSON TOC which is then brought together by PHP: http://rotorz.com/tilesystem/api

As you navigate through my API documentation you will notice that the TOC on the left is context sensitive. I would like my user guide to work in a similar way.

Is there a free alternative to Prince: http://www.princexml.com/ for paged media CSS?

Comment: Although part of your question is about generating web pages, I'm flagging this to get sent to stackoverflow because it's mostly about programming to generate the pages, and not so much about websites (even though you can of course put the HTML pages on a website).

Comment: @paulmorriss I was torn between these two sites

Comment: While this doesn't exactly meet your requirements, you could use an automatic documentation system such as [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/), which allows you to output your documentation in multiple formats (LaTeX, HTML, man pages etc). Using something like this may be easier than creating your own system.

Comment: @Chris I am already using the Sandcastle documentation generator for API documentation which certainly makes life a lot easier. I tried Doxygen but found certain advantages with Sandcastle.

With regards to user documentation though I cannot see how doxygen will be advantageousness (unless of course I am missing something).

Comment: Doxygen generates source code documentation based on comments within the source, but you can also include standalone text documents (plain text or markdown with, possibly, additional HTML and LaTeX) and form these into a user/reference manual, with chapters, table of contents and an index. Using something like doxygen you can write your user documentation and API references using just the one system. The doxygen website is an example of this in action. Just though I would suggest this, if you are already settled with Sandcastle you may not want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimentation I have decided to use DITA (Darwin Information Typing Architecture). For me the nicest thing about DITA is that it is topic based which makes the documentation modular and reusable.

The DITA schema is relatively simple and good XML editors provide useful insight into the available elements and attributes.

DITA documents can be combined for purpose using DITAMAP's. For example one might choose to distribute a "Quick Start Guide" which encompasses a minimal amount of information whilst a full blown "User Guide" will contain far more detail. The beauty is that the same information can be reused for both documents; plus the documents can be outputted to a number of delivery formats:

- XHTML (single file or chunked)
- PDF
- Docbook

The process of transforming the output into the delivery format is easily handled using the DITA Open Toolkit (aka DITA-OT). This toolkit is available from: http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net which is installed simply by extracting the provided archive. The toolkit can be accessed easily by running `startcmd.bat` (on Windows) or `startcmd.sh` (Unix-like systems).

Customising and branding PDF output is not an easy task. Customizing XHTML output is significantly easier but still requires knowledge of XSL transforms. Customisations can be made by creating a **plugin** and placing it within the `plugins` folder of DITA-OT. One thing that I would like to emphasise is that once customisations have been made you must invoke `ant -f integrator.xml` before changes will become apparent. Lack of this knowledge caused me a lot of confusion!

The generated XHTML files are very simple (which is great!) because this makes them easy to customize. Adding the HTML5 DOCTYPE is not so easy though; but for my purposes this really doesn't matter seen as though my PHP scripts only care about what's inside `<body>`.

<strike>I haven't been able to find any good WYSIWYG editors</strike> XML Mind seems to be a really good WYSIWYG editor that is also really easy to use. I suspect that it wouldn't be too hard to create a basic web-based solution using something like the Aloha Editor (http://aloha-editor.org).

Whilst it seems rather difficult to customise the PDF output, it seems quite easy to generate all documentation into a single XHTML page which can then be formatted using CSS, and then finally converted using `wkhtmltopdf`. I haven't decided on my solution yet, but at least this is a viable option for those who are unable (or don't have the time to) customise the XSL:FO stylesheets of DITA-OT.

**ADDED:** After some searching I found that there is an another open source alternative to DITA-OT called "Ditac" which seems a lot easier to use and produces a far nicer output. The tool is created by the creators of "XML Mind". Whilst the tool is command line based, those who use "XML Mind" can benefit from a feature rich GUI:

http://www.xmlmind.com/ditac/

*Note: I left my previous answer because it may be of use to others.*

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time reading into lots of variations I have come across a potential solution...

1. Create a very simple "static" CMS using PHP and http://aloha-editor.org for my WYSIWYG editor. Possibly using https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp to embed the editor straight into a more relevant GUI.
2. Convert the HTML5 pages into PDF using "wkhtmltoxdoc" with custom cover, header and footer .html files. Plus generates a TOC page automatically.
3. "wkhtmltoxdoc" also generates an XML TOC which can easily be converted to JSON.

I am still experimenting with "wkhtmltoxdoc" but it seems pretty good! Unless of course there is an even easier solution...

**ADDED:**

It seems that my TOC file will need to be a mixture of manually written and automatically generated. Something along the lines of the Eclipse TOC schema will suffice where a simple XSLT stylesheet can automatically fill in the blanks by grabbing H1-6 tags plus adding unique identifiers for hash links.

This TOC can thus be consumed by XSLT2 stylesheets and then finally converted to JSON for consumption by PHP scripts.

Mock-up extract for my existing documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toc>
    <topic label="Introduction" href="introduction.html"/>
    <topic label="Getting Started">
        <topic label="Installation" href="getting-started/installation.html"/>
        <topic label="User Interface" href="getting-started/ui/index.html">
            <topic label="Menu Commands" href="getting-started/ui/menu-commands.html"/>
            <topic label="Tile System Panel" href="getting-started/ui/tile-system-panel.html"/>
            <topic label="Brush Designer" href="getting-started/ui/brush-designer.html"/>
        </topic>
        <topic label="User Preferences" href="getting-started/user-preferences.html"/>
    </topic>
    <topic label="Creating a Tile System" href="creating-a-tile-system">
        <!-- ... -->
    </topic>
</toc>
```

Reference to Eclipse documentation:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_help_toc.html